# Custom react hook and infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have this custom hook. Every time I use the returned countries in a useEffect it seems to do an infinite loop. Like the useEffect thinks countries changes all the time and have to rerender. Now I did read something about custom hooks creating a new instance of the data on every rerender. That is what makes it loop. But cant get my head around how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
export function useCountries() {
  const { data: countryData, isLoading } = useQuery<ICountries, string>(["countries"], () => fetchCountries(), {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    onError: (err) => {
      error("Could not get countries!, " + err);
    },
  });

  const combinedCountries = (countryData?.prioritizedCountries || []).concat(countryData?.countries || []);

  return {
    countries: combinedCountries,
    isFetchingCountries: isLoading,
  };
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
const { countries, isFetchingCountries } = useCountries();
```

When I remove countries from the dependency array it works fine. But when i add it it loops the useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedCountry(settings?.treatmentCountryGuid);
    setSelectedShop(settings?.legalDepartmentGuid);
    setSelectedLanguage(settings?.defaultLanguage);
    const countryInfo = countries.find((country) => country.id === settings?.treatmentCountryGuid);
    if (countryInfo && settings?.legalDepartmentGuid && settings?.defaultLanguage) {
      setSettingsFromCountryChange(countryInfo);
    }

  }, [settings, countries, setSettingsFromCountryChange]);
```

Comment: Where is the `useEffect` coed that you are using to call the function?

Comment: Any useEffect where countries is part of the dependency arrays it seems to loop.

Comment: Yh, but I'd like to see how `useCountries` is being called in the `useEffect`? Or shall I say... are you calling `useCountries` in the `useEffect`?

Comment: One thing you should be aware of (maybe you are), is that hooks run on every render. So if you do some fetch logic inside the hook, make sure you have some condition to avoid fetching every time. Your combinedCountries variable is re-created on every render, and this is what causes your loop. You can use useMemo to make sure it's only re-created when data has actually changed. This will probably solve your infinite loop problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to change the code so that countries was not part of a useEffectr.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code that you have given above. It is an infinite loop.

**Explanation of issue**:
I think your intention is to store the countries returned from a custom hook in the state that's why you have added useEffect for it. In your case, setState will cause the rerender and you have a custom hook that calls the API. It will again call the API returning new countries and again setState will cause it to rerender again. Hence causing an infinite loop.

**Solution**:
To solve this issue you have to remove this anti-pattern. This blog gives you an idea of what I am talking about: https://vhudyma-blog.eu/react-antipatterns-props-in-initial-state/.

From the official react docs: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state

Change the structure of this component to make it work to take all the derived states in the child component and add your logic there. That way only child will rerender and prevent calling api in loop.

Comment: setSettingsFromCountryChange is just a function that set som other states etc. So I'm not setting a state with countries. But i did read that you can not have a array as a useEffect dependency. So you have to create a ref for the hook data like const { current: countriesRef } = useRef(countries);

But on first load my ref is empty.

Comment: setting any state will cause rerender so API will be called again. if you have a custom hook called in same component as your setState function.

Comment: How do I set countries ina ref when available. That should put in i memory ant not do a rerender. Need to do a useCallback some how. But can only find examples where is is a html element with a ref.

Comment: can you share code sandbox i can help you fix this.

Comment: my suggestion is that you make a separate component and take all your state in that component except the custom hook and pass countries as props to that component.